# Pandas series manipulation - change x and y

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` object `x` that outputs the following when I do `print x`:

```
2     681
1     575
3     573
4     381
0     340
```

How can I change `x` to `x2` so that `print x2` outputs:

```
681     2
575     1
573     3
381     4
340     0
```

I want to do this otherwise when I try to plot the histogram (`x.plot.hist()`), I don't get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a bar chart?

```
s.plot.bar()
```

[image]

```
pd.Series(s.index, index=s.values, name='a').plot.bar()
```

[image]

---

Histogram makes no sense as its a way to graphically represent aggregated data.  Your series is just length 5... nothing to really aggregrate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Series` constructor, if necessary can add parameter `name`:

```
print (pd.Series(x.index, index=x.values))
681    2
575    1
573    3
381    4
340    0
dtype: int64

print (pd.Series(x.index, index=x.values, name='a'))
681    2
575    1
573    3
381    4
340    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But it seem you need [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
x.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Look at the [result](https://i.gyazo.com/f13816ce0fa45070a35c3243e567fb59.png) that I get when I plot the histogram with my data. On the right is what I get when I use your answer. Your answer is correct but this is not the histogram that I want. I want x=0 to show me y=340, x=1 to show me y=575, etc.. Why is it like that ?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe need `x.plot.bar()`, because `hist` counts values - get frequency of values

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you want unless you show us? @dimitris93